# node.js lookup symbol in global environment

Tags: javascript, node.js

Not sure the title is great, but...

When you go into the nodejs REPL and type `console.log('foo');`, I imagine, behind the scenes, there is some sort of environment dictionary, `globalDict`, and `globalDict['console.log'] = a function that logs to the console`.

Then when we create new variables and functions in the global context, they get added to `globalDict`.

Is this what is going on and can we get a reference to this dictionary?

I guess you can do something like

`function lookup(e) {
   return eval(e);
}` (I think...)

but that's not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we get a reference to this dictionary?

It's called `global`

The `console` module is added to global scope. The `dict` you are talking about is called `global` so doing `global.console.log('something')` will serve the same purpose

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are looking for `global`? as in `global.console.log('pizza')`?